# Tomcat doesn't load Jersey org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer

Tags: tomcat, jersey

I saw many topics about it, but none of then with the exactly scenario, and none of then with a solution to mine.

I have a simple web app with some rest endpoints. I configured this app with a Maven's Jersey archetype and everything was working fine til now.
Today I made a Maven Update Project in the project and now, when I start Tomcat from Eclipse, it doesn't find org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer class. And believe me, it was working just fine.

I've tried to delete tomcat's instalation and reconfigure it, but nothing works. I'm freakin' out!

This is the error on the Tomcat log:

```
    Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
ADVERTÊNCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:AcmeEAI' did not find a matching property.
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.73
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server built:          Nov 7 2016 21:27:23 UTC
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server number:         7.0.73.0
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: OS Name:               Linux
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: OS Version:            3.19.0-32-generic
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Architecture:          amd64
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79/jre
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Version:           1.7.0_79-b15
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_BASE:         /home/luizgustavoss/Dev/Servers/apache-tomcat-7.0.73
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_HOME:         /home/luizgustavoss/Dev/Servers/apache-tomcat-7.0.73
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/luizgustavoss/Dev/Servers/apache-tomcat-7.0.73
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/luizgustavoss/Dev/Servers/apache-tomcat-7.0.73
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/home/luizgustavoss/Dev/Servers/apache-tomcat-7.0.73/wtpwebapps
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/luizgustavoss/Dev/Servers/apache-tomcat-7.0.73/endorsed
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMAÇÕES: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMAÇÕES: Initialization processed in 571 ms
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting service Catalina
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.73
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: Marking servlet Jersey Web Application as unavailable
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
GRAVE: Servlet [Jersey Web Application] in web application [/AcmeEAI] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5368)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Fev 02, 2017 9:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMAÇÕES: Server startup in 647 ms
```

This is the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>acme.corp.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>AcmeEAI</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Acme EAI Webapp</name>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <finalName>AcmeEAI</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.25</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>
```

This is the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    metadata-complete="false">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>acme.corp.integration.rest, acme.corp.integration.common.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <resource-ref>
        <description>postgreSQL Datasource</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/postgres</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>


</web-app>
```

The Jersey jars are on the war file lib directory as expected:

[jar file where org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WqwV.png)

Something about environment:

I'm using Eclipse Luna, Maven plugin and instalations are fine and I'm using Tomcat 7. The OS is Linux Mint.

So, there's no configuration issues as I can see, because as I said it was working fine. The Jersey jar is there in the war file and Tomcat simply doesn't see it.

Any ideas?

Best regards

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution here: http://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/solved-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-glassfish-jersey-servlet-servletcontainer/

I just don't understand why it didn't work even with the jersey jars inside the war file.

Best regards!

Comment: Because you need to create the lib in web content. Actually, it should be done in web.xml